# Can`t mock FileInputStream

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have

```
@Component
public class CodesConverterService {    
private final FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory;

public CodesConverterService(FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory, YamlFactory yamlFactory) {
    this.fileInputStreamFactory = fileInputStreamFactory;

}
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void loadMappingsFromSource() {
        try {
            FileInputStream f = fileInputStreamFactory.getStream("mappingFile");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CodesConverterException("Can`t load mappings from source");
        }
    }
```

My FileInputStreamFactory:

```
@Component
public class FileInputStreamFactory {

    public FileInputStream getStream(final String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

My test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CodesConverterServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CodesConverterService codesConverterService;

    @Mock
    private FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory;

    @Mock
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    @Test
    public void whenLoadMappingsFromSource_GoodPath() throws FileNotFoundException {
        when(fileInputStreamFactory.getStream("mappingFile")).thenReturn(fileInputStream);

        this.codesConverterService.loadMappingsFromSource();
    }
```

Why my f is always null? I have tried allot of variations. But its always null. I have created factory for FileInputStream because I don`t want to use PowerMock to mock creation on new FileInputStream in my tests.

Comment: try `when(fileInputStreamFactory.getStream("mappingFile")).thenReturn(fileInputStream);`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake when I write question. I edited my question

Comment: However are you sure that your mocks are even injected? You are using SpringRunner for Mockito tests. Change `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: Changed. Still null

Comment: I think you need to add a setup method with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`, in order for your mocks to really get mocked.

Comment: Already done @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

Comment: Why not just setup a temp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what was my mistake I was using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` simultaneously. And if using it both - then mokcks have created but work not in correct way. So I just deleted `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your test in the following example, that works for me.
(Verified with `JUnit 4` & `Mockito` `3.0.0` and `2.28.2`)

The only thing I changed was the `Runner`, but according to your comments you had already done so.

I removed the annotations in the example as they should be irrelevant when the test is executed with the `MockitoJUnitRunner` and changed the return type of `loadMappingsFromSource` to easily add that `Assert.assertNotNull`.
I also replaced the `CodesConverterException` with a `RuntimeException`.

None of these changes should affect the test itself.

The `mock` for `FileInputStream` is created correctly, even if there are only constructor's with arguments present.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CodesConverterServiceTest {

    class YamlFactory {
    }

    class FileInputStreamFactory {
        public FileInputStream getStream(final String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
            return new FileInputStream(file);
        }
    }

    static class CodesConverterService {    

        private final FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory;

        public CodesConverterService(FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory, YamlFactory yamlFactory) {
            this.fileInputStreamFactory = fileInputStreamFactory;
        }

        public FileInputStream loadMappingsFromSource() {
            try {
                return fileInputStreamFactory.getStream("mappingFile");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can`t load mappings from source");
            }
        }
    }

    @InjectMocks
    private CodesConverterService codesConverterService;

    @Mock
    private FileInputStreamFactory fileInputStreamFactory;

    @Mock
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    @Test
    public void whenLoadMappingsFromSource_GoodPath() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Mockito.when(fileInputStreamFactory.getStream("mappingFile")).thenReturn(fileInputStream);
        Assert.assertNotNull(codesConverterService.loadMappingsFromSource());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  try below code:

```
        @Test
        public void itShouldReturnFileInputStream() {
            FileInputStreamFactory mockFileInputStreamFactory = mock(FileInputStreamFactory.class);
            FileInputStream  mockFileInputStream = mock(FileInputStream.class);
            Mockito.doReturn(mockFileInputStream).when(mockFileInputStreamFactory).getStream("fileName");
            CodesConverterService  codeConverterService = new CodesConverterService(mockFileInputStreamFactory);
            assertThatCode(() -> codeConverterService.codeConverterService()).doesNotThrowAnyException();
        }
```

Comment: `FileInputStreamFactory` has a default constructor by default since he has not declared any other constructors...

Answer (score -1):

FileInputStream does not have a no-arg constructor. That is why Mockito is not able to instantiate a mock.

You can try to make it a Spy and mock needed methods accordingly:

```
@Spy
private FileInputStream fileInputStreamSpy = new FileInputStream("dummy");
```

**Edit**:

Alternatively you create your mock in a test method this way:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStreamMock = 
   Mockito.mock(FileInputStream.class, withSetting().useConstructor("dummy"));
```

Comment: But I cant write it because it say that unhandled exception FileNotFound

Comment: try the alternative

Comment: I see that factory mock is created but as always, its just f = null. Even with alternative. Thx anyway for your suggesting.

Comment: Try to create an actual spy in the test class using Mockito.spy

Comment: Same problem with yamlFactory.getYaml(). But public Yaml getYaml() {
        return new Yaml() have no arg constructor

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: The mock for FileInputStream is created correctly, even if there are only constructor's with arguments present, see the example in my answer.